# Unity GUIEditor - how can I access the sprites within my texture from code

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to access the sprites under the png I've got selected. (Which has already been sliced in the sprite editor)

Example: Here I know how I can make my GUIEditor see I have Druid_jump selected, now I want to grab hold of the `Sprite` type objects Druid_Jump_0_00 until Druid_Jump_3_03 by code (without interaction of my user) so that I can set up the 4 animations for them

[image]

I was trying with the following code sample:

```
List<Texture2D> textures = new List<Texture2D>(Selection.GetFiltered<Texture2D>(SelectionMode.Unfiltered));
foreach (Texture texture in textures)
{
    if (texture != null)
    {
        string path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(texture);
        string containingFolder = null;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(containingFolder))
        {
            containingFolder = path.Remove(path.LastIndexOf('/'));
        }
        var importer = AssetImporter.GetAtPath(path) as TextureImporter;
        List<Sprite> currentFrames = new List<Sprite>();
        int index = 0;
        foreach (SpriteMetaData spriteMetaData in importer.spritesheet)
        {
            string[] slice = spriteMetaData.name.Split('_');
            if (slice[2] != index.ToString())
            {
                //CreateAnimation(currentFrames.Count, currentFrames);
                currentFrames = new List<Sprite>();
                index++;
            }

// The Code works fine until here, I need the "Sprite" type object to set up the animation
            Sprite sprite = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Sprite>($"{containingFolder}/{spriteMetaData.name}");
            //currentFrames.Add(sprite);
            Debug.Log(sprite.name);
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping `Sprite sprite = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Sprite>($"{containingFolder}/{spriteMetaData.name}");` would get the individual `Sprite`, but it currently finds **null**, while the `spriteMetaData` is actually returning the correct spritenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the image was already sliced into sprites, the correct answer was using `AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath` instead, which returns an Object array and includes the sprites under the png image. The `AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath` function does not include those.

Once we have the object array, we loop through the objects and cast the object to the sprite type and then we are good to go.

```
Object[] data = AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(texture));
if(data != null)
{
    foreach (Object obj in data)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(Sprite))
        {
            Sprite sprite = obj as Sprite;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(Texture2D texture, Rect rect, Vector2 pivot);
```

Your rect will be probably (0,0,resultionX,resulutionY), and pivot (0.5f, 0.5f)

Comment: Thanks for helping out, question though: The image has been sliced in multiple pieces which contains the resolution info, I don't get why I have to redefine the resolution of my already sprite sliced image? Isn't there a way to access the sprite within the spritesheet of the texture instead? With the above solution I assume I have the increment the x,y position for each frame with the resolution size?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html